# Variance of two functions

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a problem where Var(X) is given as 8100, Var(Y) is given as 10,000. Var(X+Y) = 20,000. If X is increased  by 500, Y is increased by 8%, such that the new formula is X+500 +(1.08)Y. How would I go about finding the new variance? I know Var(X) + Var(Y) + 2*Cov(X+Y) = Var (X + Y). I'm not sure where to go from here, though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new variance of X is just the old variance, because $Var(X+b)=Var(X)$. And the new variance of Y is $Var(1.08\cdot Y)=1.08^2\cdot Var(Y)$

The covariance is only affected by factors:

$Cov(X+500,1.08\cdot Y)=1.08\cdot Cov(X,Y)$. Thus you have to calculate the old covariance by using the formula that you have posted and multiply the result by 1.08.

Comment: Thank you, that appears to be working for me.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{Var}(X+500+cY)=\text{Var}(X)+c^{2}\text{Var}(Y)+2c\:\text{Covar}(X,Y).$$

Using basic expectation algebra: http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/461/variance.pdf

You can find $\text{Covar}(X,Y)$ from your original data given, using the formula that you displayed. And use the value of $c$ that you have also given.

The question seems to be testing if you know the basic properties of variance.